# Using Javascript Google Map API V3, how to set click even for map, but not for markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here's the functionality I am looking for:

1. When you click on the marker, the marker info shows up.
2. When you click on the map in the background, it takes you to a big version of the map. I can create that page on a separate URL.

How do you create the click events for the above?

Also, how do you disable the pan functionality? I tried `panControl: false` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

panControl just removes the pan control thing that normally appears in the top-left corner, it doesn't prevent the user actually being able to pan the map.  You probably want to set `draggable:false`

For the click events, you do something like:

```
var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hello World!'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    document.location.href = "bigmap.html";
});
```